# Inlined function appears in std::stacktrace, but main doesn't

Tags: c++, gcc, stack-trace, c++23

I have the following code:

```cpp
#include <stacktrace>
#include <iostream>

void bar() {
    for (const auto &entry : std::stacktrace::current()) {
        std::cout << entry << '\n';
    }
}

void foo() {
    bar();
}

int main() {
    foo();
}
```

On a debug build, this prints out what you would expect:

```
bar() at /app/example.cpp:5
foo() at /app/example.cpp:11
main at /app/example.cpp:15
     at :0
_start at :0
```

However, I'm not entirely sure what the nameless `at :0` entry is representing.
The point where it gets *really* puzzling is when we enable optimizations with `-O2`:

```
bar() at /app/example.cpp:5
foo() at /app/example.cpp:11
     at :0
_start at :0
```

I don't understand how this output is possible, given the assembly output:

```
main:
  sub rsp, 8
  call bar()
  xor eax, eax
  add rsp, 8
  ret
```

*See [live example at Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/fsnK5fbPa)*

#### Questions

1. How can `bar()` know that the stacktrace is `foo() -> bar()`, if `foo()` is inlined, and completely skipped in the call chain?
2. If `bar()` somehow knows its callers -even the inlined ones-, how come `main` disappeared from the stacktrace when enabling optimizations?
3. What is that weird `at :0` entry with no name? Is there a way to easily filter it out (without string manipulation)?

Comment: Try compiling with optimizations enabled and with/without debug symbols - then you'll see a difference. It's not that the generated code "knows" anything, it's that there are debug symbols available.

Comment: @JesperJuhl sure, but do the debug symbols include information about what call sites your functions has and then `std::stacktrace` makes an educated guess about where calls have originated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Question 1

It is possible to track down inline functions in some cases. The x86-64 ABI specifies that the RBP register (frame base pointer) may be omitted:

> The conventional use of %rbp as a frame pointer for the stack frame may be avoided by using %rsp (the stack pointer) to index into the stack frame.  This technique saves two instructions in the prologue and epilogue and makes one additional general-purpose register (%rbp) available.

The debugger and glibc's `backtrace` call deduce the function by the value of RSP and the RIP using special debug DWARF section called CFI. For each line of code it has the rules how to "unwind" the current state to the beginning of function invocation.
Then, another piece of debug information comes at service, called `DW_TAG_subprogram`. Each function marked as inline explicitly or made inline implicitly has an abstract instance and the concreate instances for each inline expansion. More details may be found in Section 3.3.8 of [DWARF Debugging Information Format Version 5](https://dwarfstd.org/doc/DWARF5.pdf)

It's not that `bar()` knows who called it, it's glibc who deduces that by virtual unwinding the stack using RSP and RIP and then using the inline-related DWARF tags.

### Question 2

You should not expect to get the ideal output at all times. The C++ library, along with the glibc make best effort, but that's all they do. This is the definition of the stacktrace from the [Standard proposal](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p0881r7.html):

> A stacktrace is an **approximate** *(marked by me)* representation of an invocation sequence and consists of stacktrace entries. A stacktrace entry represents an evaluation in a stacktrace.

### Question 3

The `at: 0` is a marking of the outermost frame in the ABI of x86_64. The function `_start`, written in assembly, explicitly does that. This is an excerpt from glibc's [start.S](https://codebrowser.dev/glibc/glibc/sysdeps/x86_64/start.S.html):

```
ENTRY (_start)
    /* Clearing frame pointer is insufficient, use CFI.  */
    cfi_undefined (rip)
    /* Clear the frame pointer.  The ABI suggests this be done, to mark
       the outermost frame obviously.  */
    xorl %ebp, %ebp
```

This is of course ABI-specific.

Your way to clean this out is string manipulation, or stop two stacktrace entries off the end. Usually you are not interested in `_start()` either.

## Side note

There is a very limited support for `std::stacktrace` as of now. GCC14 has some support, GCC13 fails to show the stacktrace, GCC12 shows a smaller part of the stacktrace. Other than GCC there is no support for `std::stacktrace` on Linux. The C++23 standard itself is still a draft - usually it takes years for the compilers to adopt newer standards.

Comment: "Other than GCC there is no support for the stacktrace on Linux" - Ehh, what? Both `clang` and the intel compiler can generate code that can show stack traces in a debugger, and I'll bet other compilers can as well. That statement is complete bunk.

Comment: They lack the support for the C++23's ``std::stacktrace`` feature. I edited the response for the clarity.

Comment: This is too vague and doesn't really answer how specifically `foo()` is "magically" visible in the stacktrace even though it isn't getting called. It would be good to see evidence of `std::stacktrace` using these features of the DWARF format in action.